# Extracting values from a file's universal hexidecimal notation

Tags: c++, hex

I'm not sure if there is already similar to this; anyways, here's my problem.

I have been tring to read the data of an int or float from part of a file which its content can be viewed as an array of hex bytes (in which I think basically all computer files can).

For example, I would like to read the integer of triangle number from the 81th to the 84th bytes of an .stl file; these particular hex bytes might looks like this:

[image]

Using C++, how can I do this with the most efficient method? Am I to use fstream? If so, how?

Comment: seekg to the desired offset, and read the desired number of bytes. Worry about being "most efficient" later, when you have something to benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

I would use POSIX functions (I know it's more a C solution, but it still works in C++), first opening the file, then use lseek to go to the 81th byte and read the int (or float) :

```
int fd = open("myfile.stl", O_RDONLY);
if(fd<0){
    perror("Opening file");
    exit(1);
}
int res = lseek(fd, 0x54, SEEK_SET); //I use 0x54, like in your example
if(res<0){
    perror("Lseek-ing file");
    exit(1);
}
int buf; //float buf;
res = read(fd, &buf, 4); //I am assuming that on your machine sizeof(int)=4 as you need
if(res!=4){
    perror("Reading the value");
    exit(1);
}
close(fd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using some ancient or obscure operating system, all file IO is buffered (memory-mapped) anyway. Performance should not be a concern.

Correctness and portability should be.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <array>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::ifstream f("data.bin", std::ios::binary);
    f.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);

    f.seekg(0x54);

    std::array<char, 4> buf;
    f.read(buf.data(), 4);

    // assuming the int in the file is little-endian and 32-bits
    std::int32_t my_int =
    std::int32_t(buf[0]) & 0xff
    + (std::int32_t(buf[1]) << 8) & 0xff00
    + (std::int32_t(buf[2]) << 16) & 0xff0000
    + (std::int32_t(buf[3]) << 24) & 0xff000000;

    return my_int;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unions are convenient for these problems.

Borrowing from Omar, we can write

```
int fd = open("myfile.stl", O_RDONLY);
if(fd<0){
    perror("Opening file");
    exit(1);
}
int res = lseek(fd, 0x54, SEEK_SET); //I use 0x54, like in your example
if(res<0){
    perror("Lseek-ing file");
    exit(1);
}

union Buffer {
   int i;
   float f;
} buf;  

res = read(fd, &buf, 4); //I am assuming that on your machine sizeof(int)=4 as you need
if(res!=4){
    perror("Reading the value");
    exit(1);
}
close(fd);

cout << "If it was an integer, it would be " << buf.i << endl
cout << "If it was a float, it would be " << buf.f << endl
```